# AS3 to proceed to the next frame right after an inserted movie clip in flash cs6

Tags: flash, flash-cs6, actionscript-3

I added a movie clip at certain frame but i found a problem that after test the scene,it cannot proceed to the next frame after the movie clip ends. 
How to do with the actionscript besides putting stop() and gotoAndPlay (FRAME NUMBER) to the movie clip?

Comment: i mean what to add on to the AS3 so that the scene can proceed to the next frame after the movie clip ends...really need your guys comment...thanks....

Comment: will need more info than this.... you are using a timeline? where it cannot proceed? to the next frame of the stage? please, explain better, more info, more chances you'll get the answer right...

Comment: yup..i put the movie clip in the timeline. it cannot proceed to hte next frame in the timeline when i click on "test scene", it will just play until the end of the movie clip,it stops...and cannot continue the next frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a stop on the main timeline so it plays your movieclip all the way, then at the end of that movieclip tell it go to the next frame.

```
parent.nextFrame();
```

Comment: But the movie clip is put in only 1 frame in the timeline, and i put stop() in that frame's actionscript so that the movie can play.
If place the parent.NextFrame() in that frame also, it will skip the movie clip part when played.

Comment: The movie clip inserted is through "loading external file with playback component", so it is just put in one frame. Because through "embedding FLV in SWF and play in timeline" requires 2 thousand over frames to display the whole length and the timeline span is not enough. So,using the former one, can i still proceed to nextFrame after the movie ends?

Comment: @user2196021 See these are the kind of details you need to put in your question if you want any change of getting some good help.

Comment: @user2196021 What is the "Playback Component"? Are you actually talking about a MovieClip? Or are you loading a video? They are two very different things.

Comment: ok, when you want to import a flv movie clip, you will be asked to choose some options :1. loading external file with playback component        
2. embedding FLV in SWF and play in timeline. I choose the 1st option so should be loading a video. 

Your method `parent.nextFrame()` can only be used if 2nd option is selected.

Am i right or still confused?

Comment: @user2196021 Yes you are correct. nextFrame could only used on a MovieClip.

Comment: so, any other method if i choose 1st option?

Comment: I have tried many times using the following code. Can help me see any error below? Previously, the FLVplayback got stuck on the next frame, but now can proceed next frame but the video cannot be played.
The FLVPlayback component, the instance name is named as Q1.

`import fl.video.Q1;

Q1.source = "D:\z^^^^Animation^^^\1 Question\Q1\Q1- kuasa boboiboy petir 1.flv";

Q1.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:fl.video.VideoEvent):void
{
   MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(293, "Scene 27");
}
`